# Missing installed programs in W10 search bar

Tags: windows-10, search, start-menu, cortana

In every single version of Windows before W10, when we installed a software it was added to the start menu and we could open it by either accessing it directly or searching it with Vista and 7.

I thought that the W10 search bar would have the same behaviour, however it doesn't ; the search bar doesn't find my newly installed programs, or at least not instantly ; in order to make them show up, I have to either reset the indexation manually or reinstall Cortana via PowerShell.

Isn't there a way to have the W10 search bar updated automatically ? It's pretty annoying to force an entire re-indexation just to add Photoshop or Android Studio to the start menu once they're installed...

Comment: so there is a "glitch" in windows 10 that only lets 512 entries show up on the start menu. Be that the actual program, a link to a support site, a .readme, etc....Not sure how many things you have installed, but these are also chosen at random, not by name.

Comment: but after rebuilding the index they show up, does that mean that it only takes the first 512 entries it finds ? that's a ridiculously low number

Comment: I am not sure how it decides what to display, it could very well just be what it detects first. A friend of mine has this exact issue. He has to make links to .exe's in his documents somewhere in order to launch them in a timely manner.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "glitch" in windows 10 that only lets 512 entries show up on the start menu. Be that the actual program, a link to a support site, a .readme, etc....Not sure how many things you have installed, but these are also chosen at random, not by name.

Here is a link that describes it a bit and gives you some more helpful information.

[Win 10 512 entries](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/operating-systems/windows-10-has-a-start-menu-bug-1300603)

Comment: okay I did the measure-thing command and it says that I have 127 applications, so I'm not concerned by this glitch

Comment: @natinusala Alright, well at least this is taken off the list haha